# Take columns to row based on date column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've a dataframe which look like:

df1:

```
+-------------+-------------------+------------+
| date        | status            | counts     |
+-------------+-------------------+------------+
| 2020-03-02  |  death            |  0         |
| nan.        |  positive         |  5         |
| nan.        |  recovery         |  0         |
| nan.        |  positive cum     |  5         |
| nan.        |  recovery cum     |  0         |
| 2020-03-03  |  death            |  0         |
| nan.        |  positive         |  10        |
| nan.        |  recovery         |  0         |
| nan.        |  positive cum     |  15        |
| nan.        |  recovery cum     |  0         |
+-------------+-------------------+------------+
```

I want to pivot the dataframe tobe like this in order to visualize the table:

```
+-------------+---------+------------+----------+---------------+---------------+
| date        | death   | positive   | recovery |  positive cum | recovery cum. |
+-------------+---------+------------+----------+---------------+---------------+
| 2020-03-02  |  0      |  5         | 0        | 5             | 0             |
| 2020-03-03  |  0      |  10        | 0        | 15            | 0             |
+-------------+---------+------------+----------+---------------+---------------+
```

I've tried:

```py
pd.pivot_table(df, index=['date'], columns=['status'], values=['counts'], aggfunc='sum')
```

But the results only take the row that had non-nan date. Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `ffill` the `NaN` values in the `date` column then use `pivot_table` with `aggfunc=first` to reshape the dataframe:

```
pvt = df.assign(date=df['date'].ffill())\
        .pivot_table(index='date', columns='status', values='counts', aggfunc='first')
```

Or, if there are no repeating values in `status` corresponding to a particular `date` you can instead use `pivot`:

```
pvt = df.assign(date=df['date'].ffill()).pivot('date', 'status', 'counts')
```

---

```
status      death  positive  positive cum  recovery  recovery cum
date                                                             
2020-03-02      0         5             5         0             0
2020-03-03      0        10            15         0             0
```